# How to save video into a file using OpenCV and Java?

Tags: java, opencv, video, h.264, mjpeg

Using OpenCV and Java I could live stream the video from the camera with the Java JFrame application, that means accessing the camera and capturing the video from the camera works as
well.

I want to save the video into a file, below is my code:

```
import ...;

public final class Main {
   
    VideoCapture videoCapture;
    Size size;
    Mat matrix;
    VideoWriter videoWriter;

    public Main() throws SocketException, UnknownHostException, IOException {
        System.load( "C:\\opencv\\build\\java\\x64\\" + Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME + ".dll");
        System.load( "C:\\opencv\\build\\bin\\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg453_64.dll");

        videoCapture = new VideoCapture(CAMERA_ID, CV_CAP_DSHOW);

        if (videoCapture.isOpened()) {
            Mat m = new Mat();
            videoCapture.read(m);

            int fourcc = VideoWriter.fourcc('H','2','6','4');
            // int fourcc = VideoWriter.fourcc('x','2','6','4'); // Have tried, did not work.
            // int fource = (int) videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FOURCC); // Have tried, did not work.
            // int fourcc = VideoWriter.fourcc('m','j','p','g'); // Have tried, did not work.
            // int fourcc = VideoWriter.fourcc('D', 'I', 'V', 'X'); // Have tried, did not work.

            double fps = videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS);
            Size s =  new Size((int) videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), (int) videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
             videoWriter = new VideoWriter("C:\\Users\\oconnor\\Documents\\bbbbbbbbbbbbb_1000.h264", fourcc, fps, s, true);
            // Have tried, did not work
            // videoWriter = new VideoWriter("C:\\Users\\oconnor\\Documents\\bbbbbbbbbbbbb_1000.avi", fourcc, fps, s, true);
            // videoWriter = new VideoWriter("C:\\Users\\oconnor\\Documents\\bbbbbbbbbbbbb_1000.Mjpeg", fourcc, fps, s, true);
            // videoWriter = new VideoWriter("C:\\Users\\oconnor\\Documents\\bbbbbbbbbbbbb_1000.mjpeg", fourcc, fps, s, true);

            while (videoCapture.read(m)) {
                 videoWriter.write(m);
                 
                 // Have tried, did not work.
                 // int i = 0;
                 // Mat clonedMatrix = m.clone();
                 // Imgproc.putText(clonedMatrix, ("frame" + i), new Point(100,100), 1, 2, new Scalar(200,0,0), 3);
                 // videoWriter.write(clonedMatrix);
                 // i++;
            }
        }

        videoCapture.release();
        videoWriter.release();
    }
}
```

When I ran the above code, there was no error at all and the file `bbbbbbbbbbbbb_1000.h264` has been created as well, but the VLC Media Player and the Windows Media Player could not play the video.

I am using Windows 10. Below is the OpenCV 4.5.3 build information. I did not build the library from sources by myself.

```
Video I/O:
DC1394:                      NO
FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
  avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
  avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
  avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
  swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
  avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
GStreamer:                   NO
DirectShow:                  YES
Media Foundation:            YES
  DXVA:                      NO
```

How can I save the video into a file using OpenCV and Java. It can be in `Mjpeg` or `h264` or whatever it is as long as I can have a file to play back.

Comment: report the output of `cv::getBuildInformation()`. MJPEG in AVI always works because that's built into OpenCV. any other formats require a backend, which means third party library. OpenCV is commonly (but not always!) built to use ffmpeg.

Comment: The OpenCV build information is added in the question above. I could run `ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="HP HD Camera" -f mpegts -flush_packets 0 udp://ipaddress:port?query_string`  on my Widows 10 to test live streaming over the UDP and it works. What do I need to be able to save video into a h264 file?

Answer (score 2):

According to `getBuildInformation()`, your OpenCV was built with FFMPEG, so that's good.

The issue is the **file extension** you tried to use.

The file extension `.h264` does not represent an actual container format. `.h264` is the extension given to a *naked* H.264 stream that sits in a file without a proper container structure.

You need to give your file the extension **`.mp4`** or some other suitable container format. MKV would be suitable. MPEG transport streams (`.ts`) would also be suitable.

Further, `H264` may not be a valid "fourcc". `avc1` is a valid fourcc.

OpenCV has builtin support for the AVI container (`.avi`) and an MJPEG video codec (`MJPG`). That will always work. More containers and codecs may be available if OpenCV was built with ffmpeg or it can use Media APIs of the operating system.

Here's some python but the API usage is the same:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

# fourcc = cv.VideoWriter.fourcc(*"H264")# might not be supported
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter.fourcc(*"avc1") # that's the proper fourcc by standard
# calling with (*"avc1") is equivalent to calling with ('a', 'v', 'c', '1')

(width, height) = (640, 360)
vid = cv.VideoWriter("foo.mp4", fourcc=fourcc, fps=16, frameSize=(width, height), isColor=True)

assert vid.isOpened()

frame = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
for k in range(256):
    frame[:,:] = (0, k, 255) # BGR order
    vid.write(frame)

vid.release() # finalize the file (write headers and whatnot)
```

This video will be 256 frames, 16 fps, 16 seconds, and fade red to yellow.

It will also be MP4 and H.264.

Comment: I could save the video into a `.ts` file with `('a', 'v', 'c', '1')` fourcc, but not in the `.mp4` file.  How to verify that the video is in the H264 format?

Comment: use ffprobe on the command line. for windows there's "mediainfo" which often comes with various popular codec packs (k-lite, ...)

Comment: I voted your answer up since it contains the solution to saving the video in H264. But it is in Python, not in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Just got it work to create an AVI file. To create an AVI file, the fourcc must be as following.

```
int fourcc = VideoWriter.fourcc('M','J','P','G');
```

The file name must have `.avi` as the extension.

In some OS, `videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS)` might return `0.0`. Set a default frame per second if `videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS)` returns `0.0`. I've set it to `25`;

Thanks @Chistoph Rackwitz and his answer in Python here, to save the video in H264, the fourcc can be as following:

```
int fourcc = VideoWriter.fourcc('a', 'v', 'c', '1');
```

And the file extension can be `.ts`.